# Wordpress Vote Plugin - Vote Once and Track User

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

I've been looking through voting plugins and cannot seem to find one that works for me. I'm hoping you can help me out before I have to build my own as I'm tight on time.

I have a page that will be full of (custom) posts, and I want users to be able to vote for their favorite. They should only be able to vote once, and I would like to track the username of the person who voted.

[WP-Polls](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-polls/) is a great poll plugin that has the same features that I need (track voter and limit to one vote based on username), but I want to have a small 'vote' button below  each listed post. [Vote It Up](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/vote-it-up/) can add a voting button at the bottom of each post, but does not track users or limit them to one vote.

Anyone have any ideas where I could find something like that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you able to share what you did to achieve your goal? I'm doing the same exact thing on a project I'm working on now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is exactly what you need,

http://bavotasan.com/tutorials/simple-voting-for-wordpress-with-php-and-jquery/

As you can see you can track the user(s) and vote(s),
also you can add some extra columns in your users admin area to track the votes.

Comment: Took quite a bit of editing so I could limit the user to only vote once across all of the posts, but it works. Thanks.

Comment: I'm glad you found a solution!

Answer (score 4):

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-postratings/
I've used this plugin for years.  Can be configured to use +/- type ratings or 5 start type ratings.  Can easily use your own graphics as well.  Can track votes by cookie, IP, cookie+IP, or username (for limiting number of votes by any of those)

Can include the rating on every post by including

```
<?php if(function_exists('the_ratings')) { the_ratings(); } ?>
```

or on individual posts using the [ratings] shortcode

All votes get displayed on the backend with username, post rated, rating, and date/time and IP/host

Comment: This is almost exactly what I was looking for. Do you know if there is a way to only let people vote once across the whole site, rather than just the single post?

Comment: It's not something I've ever tried to do, but I can't see how to do it offhand.  I'm sure it is something that could be done in the guts of the plugin.....

Answer (score 1):

try [WP-PostRatings](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-postratings/)

its what i use most of the time for my rating and voting needs and it keeps track and limits user to vote once.

Comment: It limits them to one vote per post. I'm looking for something that limits them to one post in total. Any idea how to tweak this plugin?

Comment: To limit one post per user total i would built a custom code simply by saving the post id as usermeta